# TypeScript doesn't have window.eval()

Tags: javascript, typescript, eval

In JavaScript I can do:

```
window.eval(userInput)
```

in a client-side `.js` file without any issue.

But in TypeScript, `window.eval()` does not exist. I get the error:

```
property eval does not exist on type window
```

How can I get around this issue?

The reason I want to use `eval()` is to execute some user created code. The `eval` call must be done on a global scope because the user code relies on some other code that I have already previously loaded  with `<script>` tags.

Comment: Are you sure you want to run user created code?

Comment: Yes, it's all done on the client side anyway, so I don't think any harm can be done. Even if there is a possible harm - I don't really have a choice because this is for a programming puzzles site.

Comment: You could do what sites like jsfiddle do and run the users code in an iframe.

Comment: You could cast to `any`: `(window as any).eval(userInput);`

Comment: `eval` is declared in typescript as a global function, but it's not part of the window interface. So you should be able to just call it alone: `eval(userInput)`. Is there a reason you have to access it via `window.eval` instead of just calling it normally? You can always augment the `Window` interface yourself to add it.

Comment: I need to access `window.eval` because the user's code relies on some other code that was already loaded into the page, so it needs global scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

Use type assertion (Type unsafe, but quick and easy):

```
(window as any).eval("1 + 1");
```

Or you can modify the window declaration as described in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19816) (Type safe)

Comment: What are the potential  disadvantages to using "window as any"?

Comment: @Roymunson You won't have type safety on the outside of the type assertion: you could theoretically write `(window as any).badMMethod();` and it would compile just fine. But it shouldn't affect your use of `window` anywhere else.